# How can I change Date pick format to dd/mm/yyyy in Razor

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

How can I set date picket format in dd/mm/yyyy
I have used this format in the model. But input type is not showing like The model that I have created.

```cs
[Display(Name = "Dredger Time")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}",
         ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime DredgingTime { get; set; }
```

I want its functionality in ASP.
I've tried some jQuery method, but none of them working.
[image]

```html
<div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="DredgingTime" class="control-label"></label>
                <input id="datepicker" asp-for="DredgingTime" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="DredgingTime" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
```

Another help, I don't understant where "asp-for" these sort of functionality works... I'm new to ASP, Its not as simple as PHP

Answer (score 0):

When you apply the the `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` attribute, Razor renders the input with a type of "date". This is an HTML 5 input type, and in all modern browsers, will be rendered as a browser control (the calendar you get by default). However, the browser control also forces two things:

1. The date will be displayed localized (i.e. MM/DD/YYYY in the U.S.)
2. The value will be set as ISO (YYYY-MM-DD) *and* must be provided as ISO. A value set not in ISO format will be treated as null, and no date will be set.

These are actually *good* things, though. The date *should* be display localized, *and* you should be working with ISO dates going back and forth from the server. However, if you are totally against that for some reason, then you cannot use this browser control. The only way around that is to specifically set the type as text:

```
<input id="datepicker" asp-for="DredgingTime" type="text" class="form-control" />
```

Then, the input will be rendered as a plain text field, and whatever format you've set will apply. However, you'll also now be discarding all built-in validation of the date. It's just plain text, now, so the user could put *anything* in there. As such, you should employ a JS library of some sort to ensure both that it's a valid date and in the format that you expect.

Answer (score -1):

Set format of datepicker in your JQuery like below :

```
@section Scripts
{
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/datepicker.css"/>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/datepicker.js"> 
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
        })
    });
  </script>
}
```

Result :

[image]